# Why won't this simple code run?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
<script>


function toD(angle) {
  return angle * (180 / Math.PI);
}
var a = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = toD(15);
</script>

<p id='test'> </p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Sorry, i'm not sure if i'm missing something, but how come this code isn't running? thank you in advance, sorry if this is a stupid question!

Comment: Move you script code at the end of the page, just before </body> tag

Answer (score 9):

At the time of running `var a = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = toD(15);` in your script `<p id='test'> </p>` does not exist.

place the script AFTER `<p id='test'> </p>` or wrap the entire script in its own function and assign it to `onload` so that it is only ran after `<p id='test'> </p>` and the rest of the DOM is available.

Either

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

<p id='test'> </p>

<script>
function toD(angle) {
  return angle * (180 / Math.PI);
}
var a = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = toD(15);
</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

OR

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
<script>

window.onload = function() {
  function toD(angle) {
    return angle * (180 / Math.PI);
  }
  var a = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = toD(15);
}
</script>

<p id='test'> </p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Note: this is a very dirty way of using `window.onload`, that should only be used if this is to be the only script on the page that requires `onload`. For more information about using `onload` properly when there will be multiple scripts using it, please read [How to Use `window.onload` the Right Way](http://roberthahn.ca/articles/2007/02/02/how-to-use-window-onload-the-right-way/)

Comment: Thank you, so i should always put the script at the bottom?

Comment: it is depend on requirement, sometime you also need to write your script in top of the page

Comment: @Samir That's too much of a generalisation, so, no. Look at the context of what you're trying to achieve and make a decision based on those requirements and the requirements of the script(s).

Comment: DO NOT USE window.onload like that! YUCK. Next thing we will have to expalin is why having two of them will not work!

Answer (score 4):

You need to wait until the document loads, as you're trying to access an element (`#test`) before the HTML has been fully parsed by the browser - you can use [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload) so that your JS is run after the document has been loaded - e.g.

```
window.onload = 

// JS
```

Comment: And are you going to answer the question when the OP tries to use 2 `window.onload =`? :)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the JavaScript console [f12] and you will see an error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

The error occurs because you are referencing the element before it is rendered to the page.

Put the script tag after the element so it can find the element.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p id='test'> </p>

    <script>

        function toD(angle) {
          return angle * (180 / Math.PI);
        }
        var a = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = toD(15);
    </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because when you run `document.getElementById('test')` the DOM object `<p id='test'> </p>` wasn't rendered yet.

Answer (score 0):

Place the script at the bottom of the page to avoid problems like this noted above, also use windows.onload http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp - to ensure the element is rendered before you cast on it.

Comment: *Always* is not good advice.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in rendering
Change your code as below :

```
<html>
   <body>
       <p id='test'> </p>

    <script language="javascript">

       function toD(angle) {
         return angle * (180 / Math.PI);
       }
      var a = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = toD(15);
    </script>


   </body>
  </html>
```

-> Please read about how web page is parse. you will clear your idea about where to write script in your page.

->object should be rendered before performing operation on it. in your code div is not rendered and you try to perform operation on it ( i.e.  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = toD(15); )

Comment: Helped if you explained why you need to do it.